# CdnFallbackExpression cause two request both cdn and local

Tags: jquery, cdn, bundling-and-minification

I am using System.web.Optimization 1.1, CdnFallbackExpression property in bundles.

```
    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    var jqueryCdnPath = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
    var jqueryBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                       jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                       "~/Scripts/Common/jquery-1.8.3.min.js");
    jqueryBundle.CdnFallbackExpression = "window.jquery";
    bundles.Add(jqueryBundle);
```

I have used above code block. When i run the application in release mode, both the CDN path of jquery and locally bundled jquery requests are passing. But actually in release mode, cdn request only should pass, if cdn request fails then only local bundled jquery request will pass.

But in my case, cdn request succeeded and also local jquery request also make request. It will increase the request count.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Regards,
Karthik.